# Storing data as a VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was wondering is there a **standard** way to save data permanently as a vscode extension. e.g.: saving a log or bool value when don't show this notification again is triggered or check first run of the extension?

If you have other ways or API calls for these specific use-cases that would be helpful as well

Comment: I don't know if this really the standard way, but I would store such data using the `globalState` property of the [`ExtensionContext`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext).
An instance of `ExtensionContext` is passed into the `activate()` function of your extension. It has other nice properties like `globalStorageUri` that you can use to store global data in files if required.

Comment: thanks for your comment, seems very helpful, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think it's specific enough. Im asking for a specific thing or any helpful api call, but the ultimate reason is obvious "is there a standard way to save data permanently as a vscode extension."